# Obtain the version number from an artefact deployed to nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

## Context

I am building a Java project on Jenkins using maven. At the end of the build a number of artefacts are uploaded to a nexus repository (OSS version 3). This is a snapshot revision so before the upload a unique version number is set by nexus and the artefacts are uploaded with that.

We are running the following command

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=nexus::default::http://nexus/repository/somerepo-dev/
```

As a result nexus creates its own version number, like

```
5.8.0-20201124.111409-125
```

Later in the job I would like to use that version number. Is there any way I can get hold of the version number that was created during the upload?

## Question

As part of a `mvn deploy` to nexus is it possible to obtain the version number nexus assigns the artefact in a way that would be accessible to jenkins?

## Why do we want this

At present we have things like 5.8.0-SNAPSHOT in our POMs, however, this is giving us problems with non reproducable builds because SNAPSHOT will have moved on. Often checking out old versions will give something that no longer compiles and tools like git bisect are much less useful.

What we'd like to happen is for Jenkins to make commits to consumer projects to update their POMs (on the master branch only) when a new version of one of our library projects is published

Comment: It is `5.8.0-SNAPSHOT`  the part `20201124.111409-125` is created by Nexus as a replacement for `SNAPSHOT`... Maybe I misunderstand your question.. Can you explain more in detail why you need it afterwards and in which way?

Comment: Yes exactly, it's a version of 5.8.0-SNAPSHOT. The 20201124.111409-125 is generated by nexus.

Comment: The reason we want it is that we are having problems with non-reproducable builds with everything asking for snapshot versions (often checking out a project from a few weeks ago will no longer compiles). We want jenkins to auto update all the concrete versions (make a commit having updated the poms) to constantly keep everything at effectively SNAPSHOT but so you can check out historic versions and they are as they were at the time

Comment: SNAPSHOT's are for development and not history. If you have issues like that you should use releases instead ... in particular if you use SNAPSHOT as deps in other project you will loose reproducibility. That's a job for releases....